# Another contour plot- need to plot circular isochrones for this data

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

Once again, I'm missing something while trying to generate a contour plot. This data should generate some nice concentric circles. When I do a pcolor plot [with this rangedata](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kchp78s1xgeh5fn/rangeMap.csv?dl=0), I see the following:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np

import astropy.constants as consts
import astropy.units as units

import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import matplotlib as mpl 

phis = np.linspace(0.01,63,100) # SV half cone ang, measured up from nadir
thetas = np.linspace(0,360,361)# SV azimuth, 0 coincides with the vel vector

#rangeMap = orbits.range(h_mission, Y * units.deg)[0].value/consts.c.to("km/s") * 1e3
rangeMap = np.loadtxt('rangeMap.csv',delimiter=',')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,7),subplot_kw=dict(projection='polar'))

X, Y = np.meshgrid(thetas, phis)  # Create a grid over the range of bins for the plot
im = (ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, rangeMap, cmap=mpl.cm.jet_r, alpha=0.95,shading='auto') )

ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
ax.set_theta_offset(np.pi / 2.0)

plt.thetagrids([theta * 15 for theta in range(360//15)])
ax.grid(True)

ax.set_xlabel("beam angle [$\degree$]",fontsize=14)
# ax.set_ylabel("theta [$\degree$]",fontsize=14)
plt.xticks(fontsize=14)
plt.yticks(fontsize=14)
## Add colorbar
cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.95, 0.15, 0.015, 0.7])
cbar = fig.colorbar(im, cax=cbar_ax)
cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=14) 
#cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(['1', '2', '4', '6', '10', maxCV], size=24)
#cbar.set_label(r"log ($P(\overline{Z_{G}} /Z_{\odot})$ / $d(M_{G}/M_{\odot})$)",fontsize=36)
cbar.set_label(r"slant range [km]",fontsize=24)

gc.collect()
```

However, I'm trying to get nice isochrone lines (like here!) for the data but I see this

[image]

Using this code:

```
# Setup plot labels that map between nadir angle and SV elevation as viewed from the earth
phiLabels = np.arange(0,63,10) 
els = orbits.range(h_mission, phiLabels * units.deg)[1].value # Returns (range, elevation) from ground to SV, getting just the el
elDict = {}
# Build a dict mapping phi to elevation
for p, el in zip(phiLabels,els):
    elDict[p] = el

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,7),subplot_kw=dict(projection='polar'))

im = ax.contour(X,Y, rangeMap, 10, cmap=mpl.cm.jet_r, alpha=0.4,
                linewidths=2)

ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
ax.set_theta_offset(np.pi / 2.0)
ax.clabel(im, inline=True, fontsize=10)
ax.set_rgrids(list(elDict.keys()),angle=15,fontsize=14)
ax.set_yticklabels(np.array(list(elDict.values())).astype(int))
plt.text(.6, 1.025, "SV el", transform=ax.transAxes, fontsize=14)
## Add colorbar
cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.95, 0.15, 0.015, 0.7])
cbar = fig.colorbar(im, cax=cbar_ax)
cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=14) 
cbar.set_label(r"delay [ms]",fontsize=24)
cbar_attr = cbar.ax.get_children()
cbar_attr[0].set_linewidths([7]*10) # 0th attribute is lines in the colorbar
ax.set_title("Spherical Earth")
plt.show()
gc.collect()
```

I want nice circles defined by the data!

Comment: This seems like too much data to be testing this problem with. I'd cut it down to one ?row? ?orbit? and then probably *half* an orbit to start, so I could see where things were going.

Comment: Well it's just enough data for theta (az) 360 deg and phi (off nadir elevation angle) from 0-90 deg -- where 90 is in the plane of the az measurement... I've generated the data for 100 steps in phi and 360 steps in theta... I can cut that down resulting in a smaller matrix and see what happens...